# debian 7.9 Duplicate sources.list

Tags: debian, upgrade

I'm trying to update wheezy to jessie and get duplicate source errors

```
apt-get update
...
Reading package lists... Done               
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

The contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` are:

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
#deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
#deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main

deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

The contents of `/var/lib/apt/lists/` are

```
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_contrib_binary-i386_Packages
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_contrib_i18n_Translation-en
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-i386_Packages
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_i18n_Translation-en
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_non-free_binary-i386_Packages
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_non-free_i18n_Translation-en
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_Release
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_Release.gpg
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages.IndexDiff
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en.IndexDiff
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie-updates_Release
ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie-updates_Release.gpg
lock
partial
security.debian.org_dists_jessie_updates_main_binary-i386_Packages
security.debian.org_dists_jessie_updates_main_i18n_Translation-en
security.debian.org_dists_jessie_updates_Release
security.debian.org_dists_jessie_updates_Release.gpg
```

Any help please, I'm new to this and don't see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: such lines hurt the efficiency of apt, they do not hurt functionality, but they may indicate some other problem,

Comment: Sorry, I dont follow, which lines are you referring to, could you explain further please, I would like to understand any indications of other problems, thanks

Comment: duplicated sources lines,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is a duplicate/extension of

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
```

Delete the shorter line.

At least in theory, there could be also more duplications with lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` files.

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ does not contain any files im assuming this is not a problem..

Comment: removing shorter line seems to have done it. Reading package lists ... Done

Comment: Yes, it is not a problem, that there are no files in `sources.list.d`. I just wanted to mention it for completeness.